# for each loop: how to step out of conditions

Tags: loops, vbscript, conditional-statements

I am stuck at creating a loop for testing filenames with VBScript. To be precise, I am trying to perform something like a jump in a `For Each` loop. The loop should test all files in a folder and in some cases it should delete some files.

But while running, it deletes a file and tries to test the deleted file against the next condition. So I look for a solution to end this check and jump to the next file but I am not able to find a working solution.

```
for each file in folder.files
  if (filename = "foo.bar") then
    log.writeline("found foo.bar -> delete!")
    fs.deletefile (folder & file.name), true
    'exit for
  end if
  if (isNumeric(firstPosition)) then
    if (isNumeric(secondPosition)) then
      log.writeline("2 numbers seen -> alright!")
    else
      log.writeline("Filename is corrupt!")
      fs.copyFile file, errorFolder, true
      fs.deleteFile file, true
      'exit for 
    end if
  end if
```

Comment: @kingAm: thx for correcting, I'm not a native speaker. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `else` as follows:

```
for each file in folder.files
  if (filename = "foo.bar") then
    log.writeline("found foo.bar -> delete!")
    fs.deletefile (folder & file.name), true
    'exit for
  else
    if (isNumeric(firstPosition)) then
      if (isNumeric(secondPosition)) then
        log.writeline("2 numbers seen -> alright!")
      else
        log.writeline("Filename is corrupt!")
        fs.copyFile file, errorFolder, true
        fs.deleteFile file, true
        'exit for 
      end if
    else
    end if
  end if
next
```

or even  `elseif` as follows

```
for each file in folder.files
  if (filename = "foo.bar") then
    log.writeline("found foo.bar -> delete!")
    fs.deletefile (folder & file.name), true
    'exit for
  elseif (isNumeric(firstPosition)) then
    if (isNumeric(secondPosition)) then
      log.writeline("2 numbers seen -> alright!")
    else
      log.writeline("Filename is corrupt!")
      fs.copyFile file, errorFolder, true
      fs.deleteFile file, true
      'exit for 
    end if
  else
  end if
next
```

There is no `goto`-like statement in VBScript; there are *structured* control mechanisms only. Read [VBScript User's Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx7b3k7y(v=vs.84).aspx) and [VBScript Language Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: sometimes one misses the forest for the trees... Thanks a lot, that should work for me.